# Linear photons?

Tags: astronomy

Commonly alluded to as light (photons). Often one comes across indications that the speed of light linearly should be a straight line. Since those decades, it is more evident that the path of light curves in the universe, at least due to bending by gravity and perhaps by geometry. So, is it accurate to depict light as traveling a straight path (and does not curve)? If it does curve, then how to account for measuring when light does follow curved geometry?

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light is the **instantaneous** speed of light in a vacuum. The path the light takes does not affect it's speed in a vacuum.